# In-App Purchases Using StoreKit Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store-connect, storekit

I know questions have been asked about this subject, but I haven't found the solution in any of them.

I am having problem setting up a Test User from the iTunesConnect. Mainly because I don't have the option to create a Test User (that Option doesn't show up in my menu). I can't create a test user so I can see if the transactions work.

This is the steps I took:

1-Created an appID and Generate and install a new provisioning profile;

2-create a App submission request without uploading the binary;

But when it comes to creating a Test User, or set up an in-app purchase like described in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide 6.4, I don't have such a option. I am logged on with Admin rights.

How do I create a test user account?

Comment: After 2 days of searching i found the answer finally. What they forget to tell you in the In-app purchese tutorials and in the apple documentation is that you have to setup a paid application's account even if you only want to test the StoreKit code. You can set up the iOS paid Application account from Itunes Connect ->Contracts, Tax, and Banking. After that you can set up a Test User and thest you in-app purchase code. I'll leave this question here in case someone else has this kind of trouble

Comment: Why don't you post that as an answer so others can see that it's resolved?

Comment: @sudo rm -rf Ok i will! Thanks, still a little new to stackowerflow .

Comment: @Rado:  No sweat!  You might want to check the green tick next to your answer when it becomes available.  It might take a day or two because you answered your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they forget to tell you in the In-App purchase tutorials and in the Apple Documentation is that you have to setup a ***paid*** developer account even if you only want to test the StoreKit code.

You can set up the iOS paid Application account from iTunes Connect ->Contracts, Tax, and Banking. After that you can set up a Test User and test you in-app purchase code.